# Empty tooltips in MATLAB

Tags: unity, matlab

I am running MATLAB R2013b. Under Unity, the built-in editor of MATLAB shows empty tooltips, as seen here:

[image: empty tooltip in MATLAB]

Under XFCE, the tooltips are showing up just fine.

My system: Ubuntu 14.04, Intel i7 4770K.

The question has already been posted somewhere else ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915939/matlab-code-analyzer-produces-empty-tooltips) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116987-empty-tooltips-in-code-analyzer)), but I think this is a Unity-specific problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I also have it in some other applications;

Comment: @don.joey: which applications? Maybe this would be helpful to know!

Comment: I have had it in Spyder (a python IDE).

Comment: I have this problem with Ubuntu 15.10 using Gnome 3

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&saved_search_id=29995) at MathWorks for this specific bug. In the bug report, there are 2 workarounds proposed:

- `wmname` workaround:

  1. Install `wmname` by running `sudo apt install suckless-tools`
  2. Run `wmname LG3D` in the terminal
  3. Run `matlab &` to start MATLAB
- `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING` workaround:

  1. Run `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` in the terminal
  2. Run `matlab &` to start MATLAB