# Matlab: Blank window after splash screen

Tags: 16.04, matlab

When I start Matlab (R2016b 64bit; Ubuntu 16.04), I only get a transparent window after the splash screen. The GUI just seems to be invisible though, as menues pop up when I rightclick at random places.

I launch it via the console, and I'm getting no errors (nor any output at all). If I launch Matlab without a GUI and execute "edit", a fully functioning editor opens.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
wmname LG3D
```

More details can be found at:

[Blank Window While Using xmonad/awesome/dwm](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Matlab)

[Empty tooltips in MATLAB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476306/empty-tooltips-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a pain on DWM.
To use wmname LG3D, you first need to install sucklesstools from your repo.

So that you dont need to use the wmname command every time you start, add it to your xinitrc file.

You may also need to change font-aliasing from the Matlab settings.

Unless you need simulink, **a much better alternative is to use jupyter notebook with an octave kernel.**